# c# unit conversion from .txt file

Tags: c#, units-of-measurement

Please can someone help? I need to create a program that reads a list of units and names "eg ounce,gram,28" then asks for a user input, and then converts and displays the result. So far all i have been able to do is get it to read the first line, but nothing else.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Soft140AssPt3V2
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Main:
string line, Start, Finish, j, l;
double Factor, Output, Amount;
string[] SplitData = new string [2];
StreamReader Units = new StreamReader("../../convert.txt");
while ((line = Units.ReadLine()) != null)
{
SplitData = line.Split(',');
Start = SplitData[0];
Finish = SplitData[1];
Factor = Convert.ToDouble(SplitData[2]);


//Get inputs
Console.WriteLine("Please input the amount, to and from type (Ex. 5,ounces,grams):");
string Input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] Measurements = Input.Split(',', ' ', '/', '.');
Amount = Convert.ToDouble(Measurements[0]);
j = Measurements[1];
l = Measurements[2];

if (j == Start)
{
Output = (Factor * Amount);
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} equals {2} {3}", Amount, Measurements[1], Output, Measurements[2]);
Console.ReadLine();
goto Main;
}

else
{

}

}
Units.Close();
}
}

}
```

Comment: This is definitely a homework.

Comment: Since the input format is in CSV? Why don't you make use of a CSV Reader?

Comment: *blinks*  you use a goto?? :)

Comment: yup `goto` made me immidiately think that it is homework.

Comment: Let's hope your CSV file doesn't contain something like `val1, "Uh,Oh", val2`.  Yeah, parsing a CSV file isn't as simple as splitting a string.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it looks like you are reading in the text file every time the user wants a result, and only the first line at that!

Read the text file in and save its content somewhere, keep the conversion factors in a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, double> convFactors = new Dictionaty<string, double>();
while ((line = Units.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    SplitData = line.Split(',');
    string from = SplitData[0];  // should really be named 'from' not STart
    string to = SplitData[1]; // should really be named 'to' not Finish
    double factor = Convert.ToDouble(SplitData[2]); // or double.Parse ??
    convFactors.Add( from + "-" + to , factor); // ie: stores "ounce-gram", 28.0
}
```

Now loop reading input from the console and answering the questions:

```
while (true);
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please input the amount, to and from type (Ex. 5,ounces,grams):");
    string Input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (Input.Equals("quit") || Input.Length == 0)
        break;
    string[] tk = Input.Split(',', ' ', '/', '.');

    double result = convFactors[tk[1] + "-" + tk[2]] * double.Parse(tk[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} equals {2} {3}", tk[0], tk[1], result, th[2]);
    Console.ReadLine();  // is this readline really needed??
}
```

Edit: and yeah - forget goto is even in the language... using a goto is a sure sign you have written a poor algorithm - well they are RARELY useful...